# Can we use a formula field value in a Report?

Tags: reporting

I have a formula field Total Project Price on one of my custom objects. This formula does a bit of calculation based on some of the fields filled in the record.

Now i cant seem to find that field to add on a report. Is it that i cant add formula field on to a report?

Thanks

Comment: is the report  a Custom Report Type?

Comment: Yes, its a custom Report type

Comment: I think i got the solution. Add fields by clicking the edit layout under custom report type and adding the field into the layout

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a custom report type
Goto Setup -> Create -> Report types

Click on your report type

Scroll to the bottom, and click the button Edit Layout. You can find the list of fields in the object and choose the field to be added and pull it into the layout. This would be available on the bottom right of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I am trying the same. But I am not able to see the formula field to add as column in the report nor to use it as filter, Any thoughts will be helpful. Thanks